# Логика создания Django-приложений в django-проекте

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте, по какой логике в django-проектах создаются django-приложения (django-admin startapp %app_name%)?

Например, я хочу написать бекенд для мобильных приложений (ios/android) который будет отдавать json.
Например это что-то типо чата. То есть существуют юзеры, у которых свой список контактов и тд. Мне нужно просто сделать django-admin startapp contacts. И в нем писать всю логику? создавать в нем классы contact, contactlist, и тд? В этом же проекте писать сериализаторы для всех сущностей?

Какая логика разделения в джанго-проекте на отдельные джанго-приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждое приложение должно делать хорошо только одну вещь (согласно идеологии UNIX). Компонуя приложения (модули) с относительно простой логикой, можно построить сложную систему. И такие модули проще тестировать.

Моделей может быть в каждом приложении много, а может быть и одна. Все зависит от структуры данных, которые должны обрабатываться приложением. В каждом приложении во views.py кладете контроллеры (view), которые относятся непосредственно к отображению страницы. Бизнес-логика не должна быть в контроллерах. Всю логику выносите в функции в отдельный файл, например utils.py или по названию функционала, например chat_parser.py, а потом импортируете, где нужно. Вся логика которая связанна напрямую с данными кладите в методы модели.

Также в каждом приложении должен быть модуль с тестами tests.py для тестов именно этого приложения.

P.S. Про структуру приложения хорошо написано в Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices for Django

Пример для приложения:

```
ios_app /
    models.py -- модели
    views.py -- view для отображения страниц
   * admin.py -- описываем отображение модели в админке
    urls.py -- урлы
   * forms.py -- формы
   * validators.py -- валидаторы форм 
   * middleware.py 
   * tasks.py -- задания для celery
    tests.py -- тесты
   * handlers.py
   * utils.py
   * templatetags/ -- теги для шаблонов
        my_tags.py
    migrations/ -- миграции (создается автоматически при миграции)
```